# How to identify duplicate rows having value within data range in oracle

Tags: oracle, duplicates

I want to identify rows where value in Name column is same and value in start/ end column lies within range of Start and End value of another row...
for eg. for me row with ID value 4 & 1 are duplicate because they have same value in Name column and value in start column 26 of ID 4 lies within start & End values of ID 1 (24-56)

**ID    Name    Start   End**

*1  Adam    24  56*

2   Max 1   5

3   Neil    6   4

*4  Adam    26  30*

Comment: You mean, "How to identify rows with overlapping ranges"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` for this:

```
select * 
from yourtable y
where exists (
  select 1
  from yourtable y2
  where y.id <> y2.id 
    and y.name = y2.name
    and (y2.startfield between y.startfield and y.endfield
         or
         y.startfield between y2.startfield and y2.endfield))
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/04594/2)

I wasn't completely sure from your question if the end range had to be included as well.  If so, you'll need to add that to the `where` criteria:

```
select * 
from yourtable y
where exists (
  select 1
  from yourtable y2
  where y.id <> y2.id 
    and y.name = y2.name
    and ((y2.startfield > y.startfield and y2.endfield < y.endfield)
         or
         (y.startfield > y2.startfield and y.endfield < y2.endfield)))
```